# To manage the mandatory fields in magento

Tags: magento

Hello Can any one help me to make the telephone field as option in admin panel and front end in magento.?
I already tried all the solution but it is little bit confusing for me to understand

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions purely about Magento configuration are better suited to the [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?